# Add the time in a log name using logger

Tags: python, logging, time

I am trying to add in multiple log files into a Logs folder, but instead of having to change the code each time you start the program, i want to make the log file's name "Log(the time).log". I'm using logger at the moment, but i can switch. I've also imported time.

**Edit:** Here is some of the code i am using:

`import logging`
`logger = logging.getLogger('k')`
`hdlr = logging.FileHandler('Path to the log file/log.log')`
`formatter = logging.Formatter('At %(asctime)s, KPY returned %(message)s at level %(levelname)s`
`hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)`
`logger.addHandler(hdlr)`
`logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`
`logger.info('hello')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from another website.

You have to change the hdlr to:

({FOLDER LOCATION}/Logs/log{}.log'.format(datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S_%f')))

Answer (score 1):

```
import logging
import time

fname = "Log({the_time}).log".format(the_time=time.time())
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename=fname)

logging.info('hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it when you set the `FileHandler` for the logging object. Use `datetime` instead of time so that you can include the date for each instance of the log in order to differentiate logs on different days at the same time.

```
fh = logging.FileHandler("Log"+str(datetime.datetime.now())+'.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: name 'datetime' is not defined

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it but still get 'OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Path to the log file\\Logs\\log2018-06-03 09:53:07.712997.log'